# Sympl Example - Source Code?

Tags: dynamic-language-runtime

I am exploring DLR runtime, and i see that there is a nice documentation on Sympl language. Does anyone know where can i find the source code for this sample project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this documentation for Sympl which has lot of examples explained in very simple and useful manner. It might be of help to you.

http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=dlr&DownloadId=74709